# Group/cluster objects by multiple properties/keys and merge intersecting groups

Tags: algorithm, set, grouping

Aim is to group (cluster) objects into non-intersecting sets (clusters) based on the multiple properties. However not by a combination of the properties. Here is the algorithm explained in the human language.

- There is an array of objects.
- There are two special properties in the objects by which all the objects should be grouped/clustered.
- First, group the objects by the first property `p1`.
- Thus we have divided the original array into several non-intersecting clusters.
- If any object’s `p2` property is matching any object from the **other** cluster, the two clusters should be merged into one.

Here is an example:

```
const items = [
      { a: 'file1', b: 'D1', s: 'S0' },
      { a: 'file2', b: 'D1', s: 'S1' },
      { a: 'file3', b: 'D1', s: 'S2' },
      { a: 'file4', b: 'D1', s: 'S2' },
      { a: 'file5', b: 'D2', s: 'S1' },
      { a: 'file6', b: 'D2', s: 'S5' },
      { a: 'file7', b: 'D3', s: 'S6' },
      { a: 'file8', b: 'D3', s: 'S7' },
    ];
```

Here, first property is `b` and the second property is `s`.

- Grouping by `b` gives us clusters `file1-file4`, `file5-file6`, `file7-file8`.
- `file2` has `s=S1` and so `file5` does. They are in different clusters, so the clusters should be merged together. Now we have unified big cluster `file1-file6`.
- Cluster `file7-file8` does not *intersect* any other cluster in property `s`, so it stays isolated.

Here is the graphic representation of the main specialty of the algorithm:

[image: Algoritm]

**Q1**: Is there any well-known algorithm for such a task/problem?

**Q2**: What approach would be suggested to implement the described algorithm?

The programming language of the project is Node.js, however answer in any programming language is welcome.

Comment: Seems similar or even duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967064/union-of-all-intersecting-sets

Comment: Found out that the task is called “Finding a partition of the set based on the described equivalence relation”: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems ad-hoc, and may not have a standard algorithm, even though the disjoint-set data structure (union-find algorithm) seems useful.

First of all, the number of clusters `k` is `<=` unique values of `b` properties.

So, we can create our `clusters` with the size `k`. We need to assign elements from items to these `k` clusters (some clusters may be empty).

First, we can run a linear scan on `b` features to assign each of them to a cluster. `O(n)`

Now, for each cluster, we calculate `SF` = `set(s features)`.

For example, for cluster 1: (file1-4) will have `SF` `set(s features)` = `{S0, S1, S2}` as these are the unique `s` parameters in that cluster.

We then search, for each element in each cluster if the `s` parameter of that element matches with any element from any other clusters' `SF`, then we merge them, make both of their parents the same (union-find). This step will have complexity O(n . k . log(K)).